# Excel VBA: For Loop calculates everything but last row. Text header in first row needs missed

Tags: excel, for-loop, worksheet, vba

I have managed to solve a problem whereby I got VBA to ignore the header row of my sheet and perform a calculation on the remaining data. Code below. However now that I have it working it misses the very last row, no matter how many rows of data I am working with. There is no reason in the data for this - the last row has values and the same type of values as the rows where the code worked.

Column E is the only column that has data in all cells. When I used "For i = 1 to ..." I received a Run-time Error 13, when I changed this to "For i = 2 to ..." the code worked.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CalcTotalLTA()

Dim i As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Input")

'counts the no. of rows in E and loops through all
For i = 2 To ws.Range("E2", ws.Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

'Identifies rows where columns BU has a value
If ws.Cells(i, 73).Value <> "" Then

'calculate Total LTA

ws.Cells(i, 76).NumberFormat = "0.00"
ws.Cells(i, 76).Value = ws.Cells(i, 73).Value * 20

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `For i = 2 To ws.Range("E2", ws.Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count` to `For i = 2 To ws.Range("E2", ws.Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count + 1`.

Let's say you have 10 rows of data, located on rows 2-11. Your code says "From rows 2 to 10, do this logic." But you want to do it on rows 2-11.

Comment: Thanks very much, knew it would be something simple!

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Sub CalcTotalLTA()

Dim i As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lngLRow As Long

    Set ws = Worksheets("Input")

    With ws
        lngLRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        'counts the no. of rows in E and loops through all
        For i = 2 To lngLRow
        'Identifies rows where columns BU has a value
            If .Cells(i, 73).Value <> "" Then
                'calculate Total LTA
                .Cells(i, 76).NumberFormat = "0.00"
                .Cells(i, 76).Value = .Cells(i, 73).Value * 20
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but the above comment worked, so marked it as solved.